# Sitecore 8.1: I would like to send out unique discount code to individual customers using Sitecore 8.1 Email Experience Manager. How can I do so?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I have searched online and couldn't find any answer. So I am hoping that there will be someone that can help me!

I am using Sitecore 8.1 at the moment and I am having a problem to insert unique discount code into my email template so that each individual customer can receive an different code.

Can anyone let me know, whether Sitecore 8.1 allows me to do the following?

1. I can do so by setting a "discount field" into the email template, so that it can call the CSV file that contains various discount codes and match them into that discount field. After that, when I try to blast out the email, I can, once again, match the discount field to the recipient field and make sure each customer will receive a unique discount code?
2. If not, can anyone suggest an alternative method for me?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: yes, first scenario could be done using Sitecore ExM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this scenario I would use a Custom Token in your email message to display the discount code.

E.g. Dear xxx Your discount code is $discountcode$

Because the discount code is unique to each customer you need to store the discount code against the contact in xDB.

So you'll need to:

1. Add the discount code to the Subscriber profile in the core database
2. Modify the getXdbContactRecipient in the EXM Config pipeline processor to load the discount code info.

Explained in full here:

https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2015/07/01/exm-token-replacement-in-messages-with-a-contact-custom-field/